Merging pandas dataframes with inconsistencies
I have 2 pandas dataframes SC and SB.

SC contains data on football player physical statistics in a competition.
SB contains data on football player tracking statistics in a competition.

# Sample data for SC (physical statistics)
data_sc = {
    'Player ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Player': ['Cristiano Ronaldo', 'Leo Messi', 'Neymar Jr.', 'Erling Haaland'],
    'D.O.B.': ['1985-02-05', '1987-06-24', '1992-02-05', '1991-06-28'],
    'Competition': ['La Liga', 'La Liga', 'Ligue 1', 'Premier League'],
    'SC Rating': [90, 91, 92, 93],
}

SC = pd.DataFrame(data_sc)

# Sample data for SB (tracking statistics)
data_sb = {
    'Player ID': [101, 102, 103, 104],
    'Player': ['Cristiano Ronaldo dos Santos Aveiro', 'Lionel Messi', 'Neymar', 'Erling Haland'],
    'D.O.B.': ['1985-02-05', '1987-06-23', '1992-02-05', '1991-06-29'],
    'Competition': ['La Liga', 'La Liga', 'Ligue 1', 'Premier League'],
    'SB Rating': [91, 92, 93, 94],
}

SB = pd.DataFrame(data_sb)

Desired Output:
   Player ID              Player      D.O.B.     Competition  SC Rating  SB Rating
0          1   Cristiano Ronaldo  1985-02-05         La Liga         90         91
1          2        Lionel Messi  1987-06-24         La Liga         91         92
2          3          Neymar Jr.  1992-02-05         Ligue 1         92         93
3          4      Erling Haaland  1991-06-28  Premier League         93         94

Both dataframes have these features in common: Player ID, Player, D.O.B., Competition.
I want to merge these dataframes, however they are from different data sources and therefore have different formats and conventions for their variables. While both dataframes have a feature 'Player ID' with unique numerical values, the ID's are different in the datasets (i.e. different ID values for the same player).
The issue is that there are inconsistencies in the formatting for these features. For example, the names in Player can be different between the dataframes, if the player has multiple names then SC might use a different variation (and/or spelling) of the player's name than SB. Additionally, there are inconsistencies in the player's D.O.B. such that SC and SB will have different dates of birth for the same player.
How should I approach this merge?

Please be explicit, provide a [mre] of your two inputs (as code), explain the logic, and provide the matching expected output.

You forgot the expected output. But in short, this is a merge with partial strings, already discussed on SO. Make sure to check the existing questions first ;)

Use fuzzywuzzy to do a match score on the player names. Then also allow for a certain tolerance on the DOB. So something like this:
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from datetime import timedelta

# Sample data for SC (physical statistics)
data_sc = {
    'Player ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Player': ['Cristiano Ronaldo', 'Leo Messi', 'Neymar Jr.', 'Erling Haaland'],
    'D.O.B.': ['1985-02-05', '1987-06-24', '1992-02-05', '1991-06-28'],
    'Competition': ['La Liga', 'La Liga', 'Ligue 1', 'Premier League'],
    'SC Rating': [90, 91, 92, 93],
}

SC = pd.DataFrame(data_sc)

# Sample data for SB (tracking statistics)
data_sb = {
    'Player ID': [101, 102, 103, 104],
    'Player': ['Cristiano Ronaldo dos Santos Aveiro', 'Lionel Messi', 'Neymar', 'Erling Haland'],
    'D.O.B.': ['1985-02-05', '1987-06-23', '1992-02-05', '1991-06-29'],
    'Competition': ['La Liga', 'La Liga', 'Ligue 1', 'Premier League'],
    'SB Rating': [91, 92, 93, 94],
}

SB = pd.DataFrame(data_sb)




def fuzzy_date_matching_with_score(df1, df2, player_key1, player_key2, date_key1, date_key2, threshold=90, date_tolerance_days=1):
    # Fuzzy matching for player names and storing the best match and its score
    matches = df1[player_key1].apply(
        lambda x: process.extractOne(x, df2[player_key2]))  # Use extractOne to get the best match and its score
    
    # Only keep matches with a score above the threshold
    df1['match_name'] = matches.apply(lambda x: x[0] if x[1] >= threshold else None)
    df1['match_score'] = matches.apply(lambda x: x[1] if x[1] >= threshold else None)  # Store the score

    # Prepare for date comparison by ensuring dates are datetime objects
    df1[date_key1] = pd.to_datetime(df1[date_key1])
    df2[date_key2] = pd.to_datetime(df2[date_key2])

    # Expand df2 for merging
    df2_expanded = pd.concat([
        df2.assign(**{date_key2: df2[date_key2] + timedelta(days=i)})
        for i in range(-date_tolerance_days, date_tolerance_days + 1)
    ])

    # Merge based on exact match for dates now and fuzzy matched names
    merged = pd.merge(df1, df2_expanded, left_on=[date_key1, 'match_name'], right_on=[date_key2, player_key2])
    # Include only the rows where there is a match name
    return merged[merged['match_name'].notna()]


merged_df = fuzzy_date_matching_with_score(SC, SB, 'Player', 'Player', 'D.O.B.', 'D.O.B.', threshold=70, date_tolerance_days=1)

Output:
print(merged_df.to_string())
   Player ID_x           Player_x     D.O.B.   Competition_x  SC Rating                           match_name  match_score  Player ID_y                             Player_y   Competition_y  SB Rating
0            1  Cristiano Ronaldo 1985-02-05         La Liga         90  Cristiano Ronaldo dos Santos Aveiro           90          101  Cristiano Ronaldo dos Santos Aveiro         La Liga         91
1            2          Leo Messi 1987-06-24         La Liga         91                         Lionel Messi           76          102                         Lionel Messi         La Liga         92
2            3         Neymar Jr. 1992-02-05         Ligue 1         92                               Neymar           90          103                               Neymar         Ligue 1         93
3            4     Erling Haaland 1991-06-28  Premier League         93                        Erling Haland           96          104                        Erling Haland  Premier League         94


You can use fuzzywuzzy a similarity score algorithm that computes how similar are 2 compared strings:
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def create_similarity_dict(df1, df2):
    # Create a list to store the scores
    scores = []
    for i in df1.Player:
        for j in df2.Player:
            score = fuzz.ratio(i, j)
            scores.append((i, j, score))
    
    # Create a dataframe from the scores
    df_scores = pd.DataFrame(scores, columns=['Player_SC', 'Player_SB', 'Score'])
    max_scores = df_scores.groupby(['Player_SC'])['Score'].max().reset_index()
    df_merge = df_scores.merge(max_scores, on=['Player_SC', 'Score'])
    
    # Extract the dictionary from the highest scores matches
    dict_merge = df_merge.set_index('Player_SC')['Player_SB'].to_dict()

    return dict_merge

dict_merge = create_similarity_dict(SC, SB)

# Map the dictionary to the SC dataframe
SC['Player'] = SC['Player'].map(dict_merge)

# Eventually merge the two dataframes
merged_df = SC.merge(SB, on='Player', how='inner')

This approach should brings the following result:
|    |   Player ID_x | Player                              | D.O.B._x   | Competition_x   |   SC Rating |   Player ID_y | D.O.B._y   | Competition_y   |   SB Rating |
|---:|--------------:|:------------------------------------|:-----------|:----------------|------------:|--------------:|:-----------|:----------------|------------:|
|  0 |             1 | Cristiano Ronaldo dos Santos Aveiro | 1985-02-05 | La Liga         |          90 |           101 | 1985-02-05 | La Liga         |          91 |
|  1 |             2 | Lionel Messi                        | 1987-06-24 | La Liga         |          91 |           102 | 1987-06-23 | La Liga         |          92 |
|  2 |             3 | Neymar                              | 1992-02-05 | Ligue 1         |          92 |           103 | 1992-02-05 | Ligue 1         |          93 |
|  3 |             4 | Erling Haland                       | 1991-06-28 | Premier League  |          93 |           104 | 1991-06-29 | Premier League  |          94 |


You can play around with the different similarity metrics that fuzzywuzzy makes available.
